# Identity in Markov Processes

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I want to know if my reasoning here is correct, it seems simple enough but I just want clarification (I am considering the proof that if a Markov process satisfies the detailed balance condition, then it is reversible).

If $X_{t}$ is a discrete state space Markov process, let $\pi_{x}^{(n)} = P(X_{n} = x)$, $\pi$ be the stationary distribution and $P(X_{n+1}=y|X_{n}=x) = P_{xy}$.

Then,

$P(X_{n} = x |X_{n+1}=y) = \large\frac{P(X_{n+1}=y|X_{n}=x)P(X_{n}=x)}{P(X_{n+1}=y)} = \frac{P_{xy}P(X_{n}=x)}{P(X_{n+1}=y)} = \large\frac{P_{xy}\pi_{x}}{\pi_{y}}$.

It is the last equality that isn't quite so obvious to me.

Can I justify it by saying that in fact:

$\large\frac{P_{xy}P(X_{n}=x)}{P(X_{n+1}=y)} = \large\frac{P_{xy}\pi_{x}^{(n)}}{\pi_{y}^{(n+1)}}$,

but since $\pi^{(n)} \rightarrow \pi$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and since 
$P(X_{n} = x |X_{n+1}=y)$ is constant, I can let $n \rightarrow \infty$ in the above, so that

$\large\frac{P_{xy}\pi_{x}^{(n)}}{\pi_{y}^{(n+1)}} =\large\frac{P_{xy}\pi_{x}}{\pi_{y}}$?

Thanks for your insight and thoughts.

Comment: I think you are supposed to assume that $X_0\sim \pi$, and therefore $X_n\sim\pi$ for all $n\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are putting together two different things here; the stationary distribution, and the probability of a transition (and for that matter, that of a path).

The stationary distribution gives you the probability that your process is in a specific state at **any** given time, provided that your process reached a "stationary evolution". I intentionally put this between quotes, because we say "steady state", and yet we're not talking about the same "states". As a consequence of what I said, the stationary distribution should not depend on $n$ at all, it is *constant*. You can find this distribution typically by analyzing the spectrum of the transition matrix associated with your process.

Speaking of which; the probability of a specific transition in your chain is given by the transition matrix, which defines your process altogether. Note that I am talking about **first order** Markov processes here; we couldn't define higher-order processes with matrices. The first-order hypothesis, along with the steady-state and a few others (ergodicity, conservation, ..) are the premisses to the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations, which I believe are the equations you are trying to understand.

As a result of the first-order hypothesis, the probability of any *path* longer than two states is simply the probability of the last transition in this path. Now if you are in a situation where you can measure your state at a given time $t$, then you can compute the probability of being in each single state at past time $t-1$ or future time $t+1$, *knowing that* you're in a given state at time $t$. This is a sort of "*conditional distribution*", and you should proceed like you did, using the Bayes rule, or more simply with conservation rules dictated by the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations.

Either way, my main point is that the stationary distribution is by definition stationary, and should therefore not depend on the time. This should clarify your thoughts :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, I appreciate it. It has put some light on other things, but I know more about stationarity than my question seems to have implied.

I think my problem is solved via Bryon's comment to my question.